# Can't Launch Steam No Errors In terminal (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: games, steam

I am suddenly unable to launch steam or any steam titles in Ubuntu 14.04. If I try to launch from the console I get

```
> Running Steam on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled
> automatically
```

Then the process immediately exits and I get no further output. I've been searching around but most other posts regarding steam not launching involve actual errors being reported to the console.

I tried removing and purging my steam installation, then I reinstalled from the latest .deb on the steam website.

There was no change in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up running

```
steam --reset
```

That got the the steam client to launch again and load the ui. It did show the following errors but continued loading

This might be helpful though. I just ran steam --reset and then tried again. Now I am actually getting some errors

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:

    libv8.so
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0
    libXtst.so.6
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
    libavcodec.so.56
    libavformat.so.56
    libavresample.so.2
    libavutil.so.54
    libswscale.so.3
```

It's possible I'll run into some other issues down the road as a result, but that gets me past the initial issue for this ticket. Hope this helps someone else.